# Event Calender Time Set in Code Different than Time Zone Setting in Spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

A spreadsheet that I've shared with someone in the U.S. is creating dates that don't match my date and time in the U.K.  The spreadsheet is set to the correct time, London time.

The settings can be opened from the FILE, SPREADSHEET menu.

I enter a date in a sheet cell from my computer in the U.K., and the date (time) gets changed by the code.

Here is the code:

```html
function fncAddCalenderEvent(argDataToAdd) {
  var objDate = {"JobDate": "March 13, 2015 11:30:00"};
  
  var cal = CalendarApp.getDefaultCalendar();
  //var calName = cal.getName();
  //var calDesc = cal.getDescription();

  var calndrTitle = "test Title";
  
  var dateFromObj = objDate["JobDate"];
  var startDate = new Date(dateFromObj);

  var end = new Date(startDate);
   
  var jobDescrptn = "Test Job Description";

  var event = cal.createEvent(calndrTitle, startDate, end, {
    description : jobDescrptn
  });

};
```

The time from the object in the code is 11:30, but the calender time in the U.K. gets set to 7:30 if I run the code from my computer in the U.K.  If the user in the U.S. runs the code, the time is set correctly for them in their calender.  I want the time to be the correct U.K. time, not the U.S. time.  My calender in the U.K. is London time and the shared spreadsheet is set to London time.  And I'm running the spreadsheet from my computer in the U.K.  Why is the code entering the wrong time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though the spreadsheet time is set correctly, the script editor also has a time setting.  Use the FILE menu:

[image: Project File]

And view the project properties:

[image: Project Properties]

If the time zone is something other than your local time zone, the date/time functions in the code will coerce the time and date to whatever time zone is set in the script editor.  Change the time zone in the script editor properties, and see if that fixes the problem.